# How to make apache Camel Quartz2 firenow to work consistently

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz2 which is bundled in apache camel 2.23.2. I am using the "fireNow" feature to trigger the job immediately after the deployment. but it doesn't work consistently.

Sometimes it gets triggered after a long time, and some time it doesn't get triggered.

The problem doesn't occur very frequently. i tried enabling the logs to figure out whats going on. i didn't see any error message. only difference what i found between working and non working job is the order in which Consumer is invoked

**Working Logs**

org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Setting org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true to ensure QuartzScheduler(s) will be enlisted in JMX.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Creating SchedulerFactory: 1557418314584-Timer_Issue with properties: {org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true, org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true, org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=1557418314584-Timer_Issue, org.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=true, org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=1}| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Create and initializing scheduler.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Storing camelContextName=Timer_Issue into Quartz Context space.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Creating new CamelJob.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Created jobDetail=JobDetail 'Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721': jobClass: 'org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: false requestsRecovers: false| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Creating SimpleTrigger.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Setting user extra triggerParameters {repeatCount=0, repeatInterval=0}| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Created trigger=Trigger 'Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721': triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 1 nextFireTime: null| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzHelper##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Adding camelContextName=Timer_Issue, endpointUri=quartz2://TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721?fireNow=true&trigger.repeatCount=0&trigger.repeatInterval=0 into job data map.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Job Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721 (triggerType=SimpleTriggerImpl, jobClass=CamelJob) is scheduled. Next fire date is Thu May 09 16:11:56 UTC 2019| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Storing camelContextName=Timer_Issue into Quartz Context space.|
**"
org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Starting scheduler.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzConsumer##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Starting consumer: Consumer[quartz2://TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721?fireNow=true&trigger.repeatCount=0&trigger.repeatInterval=0]| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob##anonymous#1557418314584-Timer_Issue_Worker-1####na#na#na#na#Running CamelJob jobExecutionContext=JobExecutionContext: trigger: 'Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721 job: Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721 fireTime: 'Thu May 09 16:11:56 UTC 2019 scheduledFireTime: Thu May 09 16:11:56 UTC 2019 previousFireTime: 'null nextFireTime: null isRecovering: false refireCount: 0| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob##anonymous#1557418314584-Timer_Issue_Worker-1####na#na#na#na#Looking up existing QuartzEndpoint with triggerKey=Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721|
"**

**Not Working Log**

INFO#org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Setting org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true to ensure QuartzScheduler(s) will be enlisted in JMX.| DEBUG#org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Creating SchedulerFactory: 1557418506499-Timer_Issue with properties: {org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true, org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true, org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=1557418506499-Timer_Issue, org.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=true, org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=1}| INFO#org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Create and initializing scheduler.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Storing camelContextName=Timer_Issue into Quartz Context space.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Creating new CamelJob.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Created jobDetail=JobDetail 'Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721': jobClass: 'org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: false requestsRecovers: false| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Creating SimpleTrigger.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Setting user extra triggerParameters {repeatCount=0, repeatInterval=0}| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Created trigger=Trigger 'Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721': triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 1 nextFireTime: null| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzHelper##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Adding camelContextName=Timer_Issue, endpointUri=quartz2://TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721?fireNow=true&trigger.repeatCount=0&trigger.repeatInterval=0 into job data map.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Job Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721 (triggerType=SimpleTriggerImpl, jobClass=CamelJob) is scheduled. Next fire date is Thu May 09 16:15:07 UTC 2019| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Storing camelContextName=Timer_Issue into Quartz Context space.| 
**"
org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Starting scheduler.| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob##anonymous#1557418506499-Timer_Issue_Worker-1####na#na#na#na#Running CamelJob jobExecutionContext=JobExecutionContext: trigger: 'Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721 job: Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721 fireTime: 'Thu May 09 16:15:07 UTC 2019 scheduledFireTime: Thu May 09 16:15:07 UTC 2019 previousFireTime: 'null nextFireTime: null isRecovering: false refireCount: 0| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob##anonymous#1557418506499-Timer_Issue_Worker-1####na#na#na#na#Looking up existing QuartzEndpoint with triggerKey=Camel_Timer_Issue.TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721| org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzConsumer##anonymous#Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1####na#na#na#na#Starting consumer: Consumer[quartz2://TimerIssueTimerEventDefinition3719721?fireNow=true&trigger.repeatCount=0&trigger.repeatInterval=0]|
"**

I have highlighted the difference in bold. Looks like the CamelJob gets triggered even before Consumer starts.

Comment: _Looks like the CamelJob gets triggered even before Consumer starts._
Have you tried using a small delay of a few seconds with `startDelayedSeconds`?
If this does not help or you trigger **must** fire immediatelly pls tell me.

Comment: I have tried with "startDelayedSeconds" but that didn't help.  i tried debugging camel code and i found that that CamelJob gets triggered, but i feel that the routes doesn't gets executed.

Comment: I debugged the apache camel quartz, and found that the trigger is doing its job, but the QuartzConsumer start is delayed, since there is no consumer the job exists doing nothing. quartz trigger doesn't wait till the QuartzConsumer has started.

Comment: If you just want to trigger once, then use a timer with repeat count = 1. Also can you try testing with latest Camel 2.25.x release, and report back.